# How can escape colon in a string within an Ansible YAML file?

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to change one line of my code in file /var/www/kibana/config.js during installation from

```
elasticsearch: "http://"+window.location.hostname+":9200"
```

to

```
elasticsearch: "http://192.168.1.200:9200"
```

Here I tried to use lineinfile to do that as show below

```
- name: Comment out elasticsearch the config.js to ElasticSearch server
  lineinfile:
    dest=/var/www/kibana/config.js
    backrefs=true
    regexp="(elasticsearch.* \"http.*)$"
    line="elasticsearch\: \" {{ elasticsearch_URL }}:{{ elasticsearch_port }} \" "
    state=present
```

I have set variables of `{{elasticsearch_URL}}` and `{{elasticsearch_port}}` to `http://192.168.1.200` and `9200`, respectively.

Here is the error message I met:

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, /Users/shuoy/devops_workspace/ansible_work/logging-for-openstack/roles/kibana/tasks/Debian.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 29, column 25

regexp="(elasticsearch.* \"http.*)$"
line="elasticsearch\: \" {{ elasticsearch_URL }}:{{ elasticsearch_port }} \" "
                    ^
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you need to enclose the entire line in `"`, where `:` appears.

```
lineinfile:
'dest=/var/www/kibana/config.js
backrefs=true
regexp="(elasticsearch.* \"http.*)$"
line="elasticsearch\: \ {{ elasticsearch_URL }}:{{ elasticsearch_port }} \ "
state=present'
```

See these pages:
[Link-1](http://thornelabs.net/2014/04/01/ansible-fix-colon-syntax-error-for-sudoers-file.html)  [Link-2](http://docs.ansible.com/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas)  [Link-3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/it1dm5wuCRk)

Comment: How would this be done in a loop?  I've tried this and it doesn't work.  Here's my post of the problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/1132947/ansible-escaping-special-characters-in-a-regexp-loop

Answer (score 29):

The solution that will work in any case no matter how many nested quotes you might have and without forcing you to add more quotes around the whole thing (which can get tricky to impossible depending on the line you want to write) is to output the colon through a Jinja2 expression, which simply returns the colon as a string:

```yaml
{{ ":" }}
```

Or in your complete line:

```yaml
line="elasticsearch\: \" {{ elasticsearch_URL }}{{ ":" }}{{ elasticsearch_port }} \" "
```

*[Credit to this goes to github user drewp.](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/1341#issuecomment-25339867)*

Another option is to use a mutiline string. But instead of quoting the whole string, I suggest to make use of YAMLs multiline feature. For this specific case:

```yaml
- name: Comment out elasticsearch the config.js to ElasticSearch server
  lineinfile: >
    dest=/var/www/kibana/config.js
    backrefs=true
    regexp="(elasticsearch.* \"http.*)$"
    line="elasticsearch\: \" {{ elasticsearch_URL }}:{{ elasticsearch_port }} \" "
    state=present
```

The key is the `>` behind `lineinfile:`

But let's keep in mind that this question is from 2014 and you just don't do this string soup anymore in modern ansible. Instead the ideal solution would look like this, which is much more readable and does not require to escape all the quotes etc:

```yaml
- name: Comment out elasticsearch the config.js to ElasticSearch server
  lineinfile:
    dest: /var/www/kibana/config.js
    backrefs: true
    line: >
      elasticsearch: {{ elasticsearch_URL }}:{{ elasticsearch_port }}
    state: present
    regexp: (elasticsearch.* "http.*)$
```

Here we have the the `>` behind `line:` , so we don't need to escape anything in the value.

<sub>Other suggestions: Remove `backrefs`, as it is not used and `state: present` is default so can be removed</sub>

Comment: But it makes shell scripts almost unreadable: `awk -F{{ ":" }} '/[^{{ ":" }}]*{{ ":" }}\$/{print "  " $1 "{{ ":" }} " $2}' /tmp/shadow`

Comment: My problem with this solution is that it emits this warning when I use it in when statement: `[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: ('versionlock delete{{ ":" }} no matches' not in thirdparty_unlock.stderr)`. Yes, even with `warn: false` set.

Comment: @bviktor I have the same problem

Answer (score 11):

Just keep the colon in quotes separately -

`regexp="(elasticsearch.* \"http.*)$" line="elasticsearch':' \" {{ elasticsearch_URL }}:{{ elasticsearch_port }} \" "`

Comment: Great thanks! The accepted answer doesn't really cut it for me.

Answer (score 1):

`foo=bar` is the more suitable format for a one-line directive, but as you're already spanning several lines with your parameters anyway, just change the `=` to `:`, and it won't fuss about having a colon in your string.

```
- name: Comment out elasticsearch the config.js to ElasticSearch server
  lineinfile:
    dest:     /var/www/kibana/config.js
    backrefs: true
    regexp:   'elasticsearch.* "http.*$'
    line:     'elasticsearch: "{{ elasticsearch_URL }}:{{ elasticsearch_port }}"'
    state:    present
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a string already; you don’t have to (and can’t, as seen here) escape colons inside it.

```
line="elasticsearch: \" {{ elasticsearch_URL }}:{{ elasticsearch_port }} \" "
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've found to be working consistently in all cases is a variable. For example, `vars/main.yml`:

```
fw_zone_str: 'Error: NAME_CONFLICT: new_zone():'
```

In `tasks/foo.yml`:

```
failed_when: fw_zone_str not in fw_new_zone.stderr
```