# How to use the FS in a regular expression?

Tags: awk

Is it possible to reference the field separator `FS` in a regular expression of `awk` as it is possible in the body of an expression?

```
awk -F: '/^FS/{print FS}'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use any variable inside `/ /` - `FS` is no exception.

Your script could be written using `~` which allows you to convert a string into a regular expression:

```
awk -F: '$0 ~ "^" FS { print FS }'
```

Comment: One limitation: it requires at least POSIX `awk`. Old Solaris `awk` does not work. But `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` works.

Comment: @ceving you never have to mention what old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris) can or can't do. It is old and broken and must be completely ignored apart from telling people using it to stop doing so. If you added an "except for old, broken awk" caveat to every applicable answer then you'd be adding it to almost every answer.

Comment: So you live in Barelona now, benvingut!

Comment: @fedorqui moltes gràcies!

Answer (score 1):

When the field separator is at the first column of the line, `NF` must be greater than `1` and the first field have a length of zero:

```
awk -F: 'NF>1 && !(length($1)) {print FS}'
```

Comment: I used just a simplified example. I need this for shell scripts embedded in Ansible playbooks, which require writing colons as `{{ ':' }}`. Writing `awk` scripts working on Unix files is pure pain with this limitation. Using `FS` for each colon instead of `{{ ':' }}` is a bit less painful.

Comment: ? Looks like an XY problem. Why do you awk to write `{{ ':' }}` in the first place?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24835706/402322). There is an `awk` example in one comment. It is a YAML syntax problem.

Comment: @ceving wrt `Writing awk scripts working on Unix files is pure pain with this limitation.` - absolute nonsense. Maybe you just don't know how to use it? If you post a question I'm sure someone can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton ceving *is* the OP ;)

Comment: I know but **this** question doesn't represent the problem he alluded to in his comment so I'm suggesting he post a question about whatever it is that made him say `Writing awk scripts working on Unix files is pure pain with this limitation`.

Comment: I guess that  such a question would receive a lot of down-vote within minutes. :) But I agree that I would like to see what makes him thing that it is painful in *this* case. That would be required to give a good answer.