# Unable to add string between variables in Ansible lineinfile module

Tags: ansible, command, output, string-formatting

I want my filedet.yaml to look like

10.9.75.78: /app/tmp/tmp.log, /vars/tmp/test.out
10.9.55.74: /app/tmp/tmp1.log, /vars/tmp/admin.out

The below works fine and logs the data correctly but when i add ': ' the syntax breaks and I get error

```
 - name: Logging the deployment's file details to a Ansible variable file
     local_action: lineinfile line={{ inventory_hostname }}': '{{ vars['fdetails_' +  Layer].results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }} path={{ playbook_dir }}/vars/filedets.yaml
```

Output Error:

> The offending line appears to be:
>       local_action: lineinfile line={{ inventory_hostname }}': '{{ > vars['fdetails_' +  Layer].results|map(attribute='stdout')|list > }} path={{ playbook_dir }}/vars/filedets.yaml
>                                                                                          ^ here
>   We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
>   missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
>   start a value. For instance:

I also tried this code but it too fails with syntax error:

```
line="{{ inventory_hostname }}': '{{ vars['fdetails_' +  Layer].results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}" path="{{ playbook_dir }}/vars/filedets.yaml"
```

Can you please suggest how can I inject the colons and space ': ' between the the variable in  line ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can escape colon in a string within an Ansible YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835706/how-can-escape-colon-in-a-string-within-an-ansible-yaml-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can escape colon in a string within an Ansible YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835706/how-can-escape-colon-in-a-string-within-an-ansible-yaml-file)

Comment: @VladimirBotka I don't think it is a duplicate ... as OP wrote ... the quoting with `"` did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the strings you want to insert between the variables in `{{` `}}`

```
line="{{ inventory_hostname }}{{': '}}{{ vars['fdetails_' +  Layer].results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}" path="{{ playbook_dir }}/vars/filedets.yaml"
```

If the `:` colon is a problem you can mask it by using:

```
line="{{ inventory_hostname }}{{'%c '%58}}{{ vars['fdetails_' +  Layer].results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}" path="{{ playbook_dir }}/vars/filedets.yaml"
```

58 is the ASCII Code of `:`.

Comment: Still getting the same syntax error. I'm on latest Ansible and python 2.7.5

Comment: The problem seems to be due to colon : if I replace colon with any alphabet then it works. Can you please suggest ?

Comment: Can you give it a try with the alternative yml syntax?
```
local_action:
  lineinfile:
    line: "{{ inventory_hostname }}{{': '}}{{ vars['fdetails_' +  Layer].results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}"
    path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/vars/filedets.yaml"
```