# Ansible Double Colon in with_items

Tags: ansible

The first key of my host_var has a `:`. Like so,

```
---
openconfig-vlan:vlans:
  vlan:
  - vlan-id: '1001'
    config:
      vlan-id: 1001
      name: test22
      status: ACTIVE
```

However, I cannot seem to find a way to escape it so I can loop over the list within `vlan`.

**Playbook**

```
---
- name: Configure Devices via Native
  hosts: ios
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Create VLAN
      ios_vlan:
         vlan_id: "{{ item.config.vlan-id }}"
         name: "{{ item.config.name }}"
         state: present
      with_items: "{{ openconfig-vlan:vlans['vlan'] }}"
```

**Error**

```
TASK [Create VLAN] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ios1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'. String: {{ openconfig-vlan:vlans['vlan'] }}"}
```

Any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: this should help..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835706/how-can-escape-colon-in-a-string-within-an-ansible-yaml-file

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"The first key of my host_var has a `:`"***

```yaml
openconfig-vlan:vlans:
```

A: There are variables in host_vars no keys. Quoting from [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names):

> "A variable name can only include letters, numbers, and underscores. ... A variable name cannot begin with a number."

Fix the syntax.

---

For example, include the erroneous host_vars and put it into a valid variable. The play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: vars-1-data.yml
        name: test_var

    - debug:
        var: test_var['openconfig-vlan:vlans']
```

with the data

```yaml
shell> cat vars-1-data.yml
openconfig-vlan:vlans:
  vlan:
  - vlan-id: '1001'
    config:
      vlan-id: 1001
      name: test22
      status: ACTIVE
```

works as expected

```yaml
"test_var['openconfig-vlan:vlans']": {
    "vlan": [
        {
            "config": {
                "name": "test22", 
                "status": "ACTIVE", 
                "vlan-id": 1001
            }, 
            "vlan-id": "1001"
        }
    ]
}
```